# How to make sure that animals stay inside the fences?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I put up fencing for my animals they don't stay within the fencing!

- Gates are closed
- Nowhere is there an open spacing

No answer is wrong here, I need some suggestions on how to keep them in.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your current setup?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there is no blocks inside at the same level as the fence. Most animals can jump onto blocks and then use that to jump over fences. If you can get out, they can get out. Keep the inside a full block lower than the fence in all places.